# Capture all the data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have a question relating to HTML parsing. I would like to catch text from [this site](https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/dekorativnye-oboi/?sortby=8&display=90) into my current spreadsheet, but code can only loop through each 1 page.

```
Sub Data()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, topic As HTMLHtmlElement
    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/dekorativnye-oboi/?sortby=1&display=90", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    For Each topic In Html.getElementsByClassName("ui-product-card__info")
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("product-name")
            If .Length Then x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("main-value-part")
            If .Length Then Cells(x, 2) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next topic
End Sub
```

How can I loop  the next page in the process to capture all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want  to get text from next pages on the website?
you can just continue in the way you do, but just loop through the page number:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to 96

'Do here the same what you were doing, but replace your website string into:

"https://voronezh.leroymerlin.ru/catalogue/dekorativnye-oboi/? 
display=90&sortby=1&page=" & i

Next i
```